# Extract small audio clips from large video files

Tags: video, audio, video-editing

I have a few hundred .mp4 files which are typically 1-2 minutes long. I would like to watch the videos, and extract small audio clips (1-3 seconds) from the videos. Those small audio clips can be saved in any format.

Any recommendations? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ffmpeg` should be able to do that. maybe a combination of `ffmpeg -i input-video.avi -vn -acodec copy output-audio.aac` (extract audio without reencoding) and the options `-ss HH:MM:SS.msec` (start) and `-t HH:MM:SS.msec` (length). So I would try `ffmpeg -ss HH:MM:SS.msec -i input-video.mp4 -t HH:MM:SS.msec -vn -acodec copy output-audio.aac`

Comment: As the comment shows, you should probably have been a little more specific :D Did you look for something that has a GUI, so you can mark what you want to export – or are you happy with specifying all those details at command line? Also, what OS should your wanted solution run on? Any price margin should it come to paid software?

Comment: Sure, sorry about missing some details. 

I would like to watch the video and mark locations, so figure that would require a GUI. Mac or Windows would be fine. Price range I don’t have a real sense of, but would be tough for me to spend over 50 for something to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to drag and drop your video into a free video editor like HitFilm Express. As you play the video, press a keyboard shortcut to split up the video into the small segments you want audio for. Then 'render' or export the video as an audio file like .wav.

All of your audio clips are in one file, but if they need to be in separate files, you could then drag your audio file into an audio editor like Audacity and split it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows application [M²Convert Professional](http://m2solutionsinc.com/).

There’s a “Split File” feature that lets you launch a player to select one or more portions:

[image: M2 Convert Split Files]

Once in the player, you can play, pause, seek, etc. to get to the start/end point, mark them with the 2 bracket buttons, then click “Add”.

[image: Select portion using player]

Once you’re done selecting all the needed portions, close the player window and click “Split” in the “Split Media File” window.

I recommend trying the free evaluation before deciding whether to purchase the application.

Note: The portions will be in a video format such as AVI or OGG, but it’s very easy to convert them to MP3 or other Audio formats in one step using the same program’s “Convert Files” feature.

Full disclosure: This application is from a subsidiary owned by the company I work for. It was developed using the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/multimedia)